# Rails button call controller method and don't redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, rails-routing

I am trying to call a method in a controller from a button in a Rails view. I followed some other questions on here and got to this point.

`routes.rb`:

```rb
namespace :processing do
  resources :applications do
    stuff
    post :test, :to => 'applications#test', :on => :member
  end
end
```

the controller method is simply called `test`. Here is the relevant part of the controller:

```rb
def test
  @application = Application.find_by(record_id: params[:id])
  puts 'THIS IS A TEST'
end
```

Finally, I am calling the route with this code in an `.erb` file:

```
<%= button_to 'Send to Processing', 
      test_processing_application_path(record_id), 
      method: :post, form_class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

The button renders properly and seems to follow the right route. However, my problem is that the button attempts to redirect and render the route
`/processing/applications/715707082/test` which doesn't exist and causes a problem.

How do I just make this button not redirect/render something and instead simply call the method from the page it is currently on? Please feel free to link me relevant posts or close this if it duplicates an existing question.

Answer (score 1):

The route in your routes.rb file does define the

`test_processing_application_path` as a `POST` to the path

`/processing/applications/:id/test(.:format)`

expecting to be implemented in the controller

`processing/applications#test` --

that is a file in `app/controllers/processing/applications_controller.rb` that defines a controller like:

```
module Processing
  class Applications < ApplicationController
    def test
      # your code here
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a method you should use action and remote true will trigger an ajax request and prevent you from redirection. Then create a test.js.erb file for handling ajax request to update your DOM that will be executed after your action call.

```
<%= button_to 'Send to Processing',test_processing_application_path(record_id), 
action: :test, form_class: 'btn btn-danger', :remote=>true %>
```

Hope this will help.

Cheers.